# Incrementing a column by one in trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to add let's say another student to a class.

Basically I have two tables: `Students` and `Classes`.

I want the trigger to add +1 to the student count when I add a student with that class ID to the `Students` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatestudentcount
ON ENROLLED
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Classes 
    SET enrolled_students = (enrolled_students + 1) 
    WHERE class_id = old.class_id;
END
```

But `Old.Class_id` doesn't work.

Would appreciate any help or tips.

Cheers!

Comment: Please provide your table description.

Comment: ?? what i want to do is when I add a student to a class, I want the class to add + 1 to its enrolledstudents

Comment: @GordonLinoff I belive he wants to update the Student count in the Classes table

Comment: added what i have gotten so far

Comment: Exactly  :D @EagerToLearn

Comment: What if there was other delete-operations before the insert. Then your count would be wrong.

Comment: In an `INSERT` trigger in SQL Server, the rows that are being inserted are available in the `Inserted` pseudo table - there's no `Old.` (or `New.`) table available

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. This doesn't work because `old` (but I believed it should be `inserted` as I recall) is a row not an variable object.

So :

```
declare @class_id int --- I presume 
select @class_id = class_id from old 
UPDATE Classes SET enrolled_students = (enrolled_students + 1) where class_id = @class_id;
```

But if  if there was other delete-operations before the insert. Then your count would be wrong.

Or What if the insert was a `insert into .. select from` :

```
insert into students select * from #x
```

So if you want to keep track of the correct count, this should do it :

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatestudentcount

ON ENROLLED

AFTER INSERT , DELETE

Update e 
    set e.enrolled_students = b.enrolled_students
    from Classes e join (
                        select class_id, count(1) as enrolled_students
                        from ENROLLED
                        group by class_id
                        ) b 
    on a.class_id = b.class_id

if exists(select top 1 from Classes where enrolled_students > 5) 
begin
    print 'maximum reached'
end
```

P/s : keep in mind that I haven't tested these code, may need a bit of modification but generally speaking, I think this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Awesome! what do you think I could do if I wanted to compare that with a max_studentcount before updating?

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Lets say I have a max_enrolledstudents of 5 but I have already reached 5 students enrolled, I want to print a message that says "limit reached".

Comment: Trigger's execution doesn't happen in your query window. I happens  somewhere else. So the print command wouldn't be visible. So there's only 2 ways for you : have a log table and insert that warning into it or check the count the before inserting (application's side or query window ..)

Comment: but could you tell me how could I apply an if statement to your previous answer for that case.

Comment: @Normal_Dude_LearnsCode updated. But, like I said, you won't be able to see the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatestudentcount
ON ENROLLED
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Classes 
    SET enrolled_students = (enrolled_students + 1) 
    WHERE class_id IN (SELECT class_id FROM INSERTED);
END
```